# Mapping a private backing field with MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to get a private backing field mapped in MongoDB.
My model looks like:

```
public class Competitor
{
    private IList<CompetitorBest> _competitorBests;

    public virtual int CompetitorId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type == "Team")
                return TeamName;

            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CompetitorBest> CompetitorBests
    {
        get { return _competitorBests.ToArray(); }
    }
}
```

I'm basically trying to map _competitorBests, to be CompetitorBests (which exists in my document in mongo)

**Note:** This model is shared by NHibernate (hence the `virtual`)
I can't see anything obvious in the docs.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Competitor>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapField("_competitorBests").SetElementName("CompetitorBests");
});
```

Comment: Were you able to run linq queries on the .CompetitorBests property? It blows up for me.

Comment: If the code will not work, Ensure that your field has no `readonly` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

Above answer works but as [@jereme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129674/jereme) mentioned, it blows up if you try to use it with LINQ.
Adding private setter worked for me and I didn't even have to add custom mapping in RegisterClassMap.

```
public class Competitor
{
    private IList<CompetitorBest> _competitorBests;

    public virtual IEnumerable<CompetitorBest> CompetitorBests
    {
        get => _competitorBests.ToArray();
        private set => _competitorBests = value.ToList();
    }
}
```