# MongoDB private fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a product model, it has many fields. Some of them are dedicated to front-end application, ex:

```
var GameSchema = new Schema({
    likes: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
    },
    likes_count: {
       type: Number
    }
});
```

I don't need `likes_count` field in Db, but controller returns only fields that model have, so i add `likes_count` field to db model

```
exports.some_method = function(req, res){
    var game = req.game;
    game.likes_count = game.likes.length
    res.json(game);
}
```

Is there a way to add extra data to db model when sending request without having them in db?

Please note, problem is not in `likes_count` field itself, i have different models, but the point is having extra data on db model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who still interested, <s>mongo_db</s> mongoose(@robertklep) has [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) fields, that can be used as temporary data field, that doesn't exist in database

```
GameSchema.virtual('likes_count').get(function () {
  return this.likes.length;
});
```

And note, your model must have permission for virtuals like this, so that you can use it inside controllers

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

Comment: This is really a feature of Mongoose, not MongoDB per se.

Comment: to me seems an overkill for such trivial operation

Comment: @robertklep yup, just a mistype

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way to add extra data to db model when sending request without having them in db?"

*You may be able to do so from a driver's perspective* and I'll leave that to those who know abut such things. Check out the following post [Mapping a private backing field with MongoDB C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331575/mapping-a-private-backing-field-with-mongodb-c-sharp).

*I can answer from the MongoDB engine & server processes aspect;* if you are looking for a way to flag a field in the JSON document to make it private when sent to the actual CRUD request the MongoDB engine receives then no.

However, you could intercept the JSON prior to the actual CRUD request and transform it. The JSON you are generating is not inserted until you execute one of the INSERT, Modify, or Update statements. The pseudo steps would be to generate a JSON document, send it to a broker\wrapper etc in front of MongoDB, and then transform it by removing the fields in question, then send the new object as a CRUD request to the MongoDB engine.

Comment: you mean i must convert `apple` to `pineapple` on every CRUD operation and convert back on every request from front-end?

Comment: You summed it up. It's a (one) way and not a very efficient one at that! I don't work with the drivers at all; but that's likely a better area to dig into per a brief tour of S.O and Google regarding the topic. I see the way I described as inefficient. It is a good question though; thus the +1.