# DDD implementation - repository and factory

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I write in java and try using DDD.

1. I have domain model with interface for repository, repository has interface where is implemented in infrastructure layer (IoC).
2. I would like that only aggregation roots class and interfaces had package scope public. Entity, domain service, VO should had package scope private.

App schema (Interfaces is controllers, GUI etc.)[image]

My question is:

- How save data to database from aggregation root without getters. I would like have only clean buissnes behavior. Maybe my aggregation root should create DTO object?(but is smell)
- Factory should be in domain package, application or should have interface in domain package?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53296375/455493) it boils down to the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How save data to database from aggregation root without getters. I would like have only >clean buissnes behavior. Maybe my aggregation root should create DTO object?(but is smell)

May be you are looking for ports-and-adapters architecture pattern.

Usual approach - place business and infrastratucture code in **same package** but in **different modules**

You even can make your AR non-public without public getters/setters.

Example:

https://github.com/ddd-by-examples/factory

look at

*Examples of Domain Model in code:
aggregate ProductDemand
entity DailyDemand*

in description - ProductDemand and DailyDemand not public, placed in **demand-forecasting-model** module at package **io.dddbyexamples.factory.demand.forecasting**

Now look at package **io.dddbyexamples.factory.demand.forecasting** in module **demand-forecasting-adapters** and you will see infrastructure implemmentation