# I'm writing data to a MongoDb twice from a wrapper, and would like not to

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I have a class which I want to store in a MongoDb, which wraps another class.

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public Wrapper(Thing wrappedThing)
    {
        WrappedThing = wrappedThing;
    }

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    private Thing WrappedThing { get; set; }

    public int Number
    {
        get => WrappedThing.Number;
        set => WrappedThing.Number = value;
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This works. However, when I Insert the class into the database, it serialises and stores everything twice. So the document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64135aa76c1fd27e8bb8d4cb"
  },
  "Number": 0,
  "WrappedThing": {
    "Number": 0
  }
}
```

Obviously I don't want everything stored twice. I thought that decorating Number with [BsonIgnore] would not serialise the top level, but unfortunately that just gives me a

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for o => o.Number.
```

error when I attempt to Find something in the database by matching against Number.

Is there a way to avoid saving the data in the database twice?

Comment: Shouldn't you apply `[BsonIgnore]` to `WrappedItem`?

Comment: what is `Order` structure?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: If I don't add the [BsonElement], or use both [BsonElement] and [BsonIgnore] I get a MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Member 'WrappedOrder' is not mapped. error

Comment: Does this happen when serializing or deserializing? When deserializing the JSON should probably not contain the ignored property (I never used Bson).

Comment: Given that the property you want to store is private, you may need to go the class-map route: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331575/mapping-a-private-backing-field-with-mongodb-c-sharp

Comment: You should better describe what you need. Effectively what you need (from db pov) is: ignore a field. Then `BsonIgnore` if what you need. And you should add this attribute to the field itsefl: `private Thing WrappedThing { get; set; }`